# jQuery .html() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following mark up code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Back</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="runner-row runner-back">1.98</td>
        <td class="runner-row  runner-back">1.99</td>
        <td class="runner-row  runner-back runner-back-active">2.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

I use the following Javascript code to change the values of my "runner-row" elements

```
window.onload = function() {
    var gElemRunners = $(".runner-row");
    gElemRunners[0].innerHTML = 1.5;
    gElemRunners[1].innerHTML = 1.6;
    gElemRunners[2].innerHTML = 1.7;
}
```

This code works absolutely fine and the values update properly when the window has loaded. However, the following code does not work.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var gElemRunners = $(".runner-row");
    gElemRunners[0].html(1.5);
    gElemRunners[1].html(1.6);
    gElemRunners[2].html(1.7);
}
```

I get the following error in DevConsole

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].html is not a function
```

I get the same error even if I change the .html to .text or .val. Please help me with this because I can't seem to understand where the problem lies.

Comment: Using `$('selection')[0]` exposes the DOM API underneath. This will not return a jQuery object and therefore will not have the `.html()` method.

Comment: Hmm, so what's the best alternative using jQuery?

Comment: Well you could use `.eq(0).html()` or you could just use the method that works already.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$(...)[0]` will return the DOM element. If you want to use a jquery function, it has to be on a jquery selector object. If you want to get the jquery selector for a specific index, use the [eq function](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$('selection').eq(0).html();
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem straight away :) You guys are awesome! Thanks to everyone who answered!

Comment: in for loop i had to do this any suggestion to make it more beautifull ? `$("#s2id_search-products-autocomplete > ul > li.select2-search-choice > div").each(function(i, obj) {
    $("#s2id_search-products-autocomplete > ul > li.select2-search-choice > div").eq(i).html();
});`

Answer (score 3):

When you read from jQuery object `gElemRunners`, you're getting HTMLElement and not the jQuery object.
You have to wrap the HTMLElement again to jQuery object before using any of it's function.

Try this instead (also there can be multiple better ways, I'm just suggesting one here) -

```
$(gElemRunners[0]).html(1.5)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out `gElemRunners[0]` returns the DOM API, which doesn't have a html method.

What you can use is the [jQuery.each() method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate over your elements, or you can use `gElemRunners.eq(0).html()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use a jQuery method in a non-jQuery object, because when you get the first element `gElemRunners[0]`, it is returning the DOMElement itself, not the jQuery object.

Using jQuery, you could do:

```
var gElemRunners = $(".runner-row");
gElemRunners.eq(0).html(1.5);
gElemRunners.eq(1).html(1.6);
gElemRunners.eq(2).html(1.7);
```